# Webpack 4 sass-loader import file without ~ tilde in path

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, sass-loader

Is there a way to use third-party SASS with imports like `@import module-name/path` and still have sass-loader resolve the files to `node_modules`?

If I put the `~` in like `@import ~module-name/path` this works and sass-loader looks into the `node_modules` and finds the files, but I am unable to modify the SASS files to add the `~`.

I have tried a few things such as

```
 rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      "css-loader",
      {
        loader: "sass-loader",
        options: {
          includePaths: ["node_modules"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

but the modules do not resolve.

Any ideas? I see lots of other folks with the same issue but only see adding `~` as a real fix (which I can't do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and effort, I found this is not possible AFAIK, but you can write something to enumerate your `includePaths` and add that array to your config.

The last part of each path should be a directory where an `@import` would be found.

For `@import scoped-module-name/path`

Have your `includePaths` with this:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      "css-loader",
      {
        loader: "sass-loader",
        options: {
          includePaths: ["node_modules/@your_org"] // scoped-module-name exists here
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```